# Book on the evolution of Quantum Theory

Tags: physics, resource-recommendation

Can anyone recommend some good book(s) on the **Evolution of Quantum Theory**, focusing on **history**, not necessarily on explaining the technical/math part?

The books I have read so far,

1. "[Quantum: Einstein, Bohr, and the Great Debate about the Nature of Reality](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393078299)" by Manjit Kumar
2. "[Uncertainty: Einstein, Heisenberg, Bohr, and the Struggle for the Soul of Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1400079969)" by David Lindley
3. "[Quantum Enigma: Physics Encounters Consciousness](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005H5O1DU)" by Bruce Rosenblum
4. [Entanglement: The Greatest Mystery in Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568582323) by Aczel, Amir D

They all did a good job in explaining some part of the history, but not the overall history. So if I were to recommend just ONE book I won't recommend any of them.

Actually, I find "[Introducing Quantum Theory A Graphic Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1840468505)" does a decent job of that but I was hoping to find a more detailed version of it.

Someone recommends "[The Quantum Story A History in 40 Moments](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199566844)" but I have not read it. Any other recommendations?

I am looking for a book about 300 pages (or less) and costs less than 30$ (I think that is a reasonable price for a book around 300 pages). All the books I list here fit in this category.

BTW, I added this "requirement" after seeing the recommendation from the comments and the answer I got so far.

Comment: Many many available... maybe useful Carl Helrich, [The Quantum Theory: Origins and Ideas. A Historical Primer for Physics Students (Springer, 2021)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Quantum_Theory_Origins_and_Ideas/PVk7EAAAQBAJ)

Comment: More details: Hubert Goenner & Giuseppe Castagnetti, [Establishing Quantum Physics in Berlin: Einstein and the Kaiser Wilhelm Institute for Physics, 1917–1922 (2021, Springer)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Establishing_Quantum_Physics_in_Berlin/u5oXEAAAQBAJ) and Michael Eckert, [Establishing Quantum Physics in Munich: Emergence of Arnold Sommerfeld’s Quantum School (2021, Springer)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Establishing_Quantum_Physics_in_Munich/kzMPEAAAQBAJ)

Comment: I have some questions about the books, 1. "The Quantum Theory—Origins and Ideas" costs more than 100$, why is it so expensive (for 250 pages) 2. "... 1917-1922", this time span alone is not enough for the whole story 3.  " ... Arnold Sommerfeld’s Quantum",  Arnold Sommerfeld alone is not enough for the whole story.

Comment: [Kragh, Quantum Generations](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691095523/quantum-generations) is historically authoritative and covers 1895-1995.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one book covering the whole history, I can recommend 3 volumes of

Mituo Taketani, The formation and logic of quantum mechanics,
(translated from Japanese), World Scientific 2001.

Some other books that I can recommend are:

Sin-itiro Tomonaga, The story of spin, also translated from the Japnese, and

B. L. van der Waerden, Sources of quantum mechanics, North Holland, 1967. This is a collection of original papers of the early period, (ending with Born, Jordan, Heisenberg) with a historical introduction of vdWaerden.

Comment: This book has 900 pages and costs more 200$. **OMG**. I was looking for a book about 300 pages (or less) and costs less than 30$. I think that is a reasonable price

Comment: You did not specify your parameters in your question. The book is available on Internet for free, if you search carefully. You also did not specify what exactly are you looking for: a book of history or a source to learn quantum mechanics itself. These are different things.

Comment: "You also did not specify what exactly are you looking for" But I said it in my first sentence, "Can anyone recommend some good book(s) on the Evolution of Quantum Theory, focusing on history."

Comment: Anyway I added them in my question per your comments.